# Getting Actual Width vs Styled Width

Tags: jquery, width

I have a table where I've specified a styled width of all TD elements to be 200px.  However, when content in the cells take up more space, the cell just grows to fit.  I need to be able to get the actual width of the TD element(s) but when I try using jQuery's width() and outerWidth() functions, I'm really only getting the styled width.  How can I get the width that the TD grows to in order for the content to fit?

Comment: That's weird. `width` and `outerWidth` do get the computed values. Can you post some code>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the computed styles using

```
 window.getComputedStyle(element, property)
```